# Restangular, не приходят данные

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

Пытаюсь подгрузить данные при помощи Restangular, в итоге массив в который я сохраняю полученные данные, пустой.

Фабрика

```
function dataService(Restangular) {
        Restangular.setBaseUrl('http://beta.json-generator.com/api/json/get/EkKWgIpZ7?indent=4');

        var factory = {
            getPostsList: getPostsList
        };
        return factory;

        function getPostsList() {
            return Restangular.all('posts').getList();
        }
```

Контроллер

```
function ExampleCtrl(dataService) {
    var self = this;
    this.posts = [];
    this.getList = getList;

    function getList(){
        dataService.getPostsList.then(function(posts){
            self.posts = posts;
        },function(err){
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
      console.log(self.posts);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> HTML

```
<div ng-app="example" ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">
</div>
```

> JavaScript

```
var app = angular.module('example', ['restangular']).
  config(function(RestangularProvider) {
      RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://beta.json-generator.com/api/json/get/EkKWgIpZ7?indent=4');
  });

app.factory('dataService', function (Restangular) {
        function getPostsList() {
            return Restangular.all('posts').getList();
        }
        return {
            getPostsList: getPostsList
        };
});

function ExampleCtrl(dataService) {
    var self = this;
    this.posts = [];
    this.getList = getList;

    function getList(){
        dataService.getPostsList().then(function(posts){
            self.posts = posts;
            console.log(self.posts);
        },function(err){
            console.log(err);
        });
    }

    this.getList();
}
```